# Display Allowed child node of Different Doccument Types in Umbraco

Tags: c#, listview, treeview, umbraco7, content-management

I need to develop functionality that contains contents like

Category -> Subcategory -> Content and
Category -> Content

For Example,

```
World News(Category)
      USA(Sub Category)
         USA News1(Content)
         USA News2(Content)
      Denmark(Sub Category)
         Denmark News1(Content)
         Denmark News2(Content)
      Common News1(Content)
      Common News2(Content)
```

I have different Document type for News Category, News sub category and content. 
News sub category and content are Allowed child node types of News Category.

Now I need to display subcategory ( USA and Denmark) in Tree view under World news and content in List view (Common News1 and 2 will be inside World News and USA news 1 and 2 inside USA and same for Denmark)

Is there any way to achieve this? Or any package available which is helpful.

Please let me know.

Comment: iam using umbraco 12
 have the same issue i want to create cascade dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in Umbraco to mix Tree and List view. Rather you can check on [Opten.Umbraco.ListView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Opten.Umbraco.ListView/) package that will allow you to display content of specific DocumentType in a list view. (e.g News sub category in Tab 1 and Content in Tab 2.

Hope this helps.